# Camera Clipping - far plane vs near plane

Tags: camera

I have a scene where the object (gray thing) needs to reach the camera and completely cover its view.

[image]

Camera Start Clip needs to be set at low values so the gray object can be properly displayed. However, low Start Clip values destroy the far plane of the scene (both viewport and render).

Higher Start Clip values display the far plane correctly but the object near the camera is cut off.

Is there a way to display both far and near planes correctly together in one scene? (I'm just curious if it's possible, compositing is an obvious solution)
Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, what do you have the far plane set to in the scene?

Comment: The far plane is 150m far from the camera. Clip End is at 1000m, but changing this value makes no difference. Not sure if that's the answer to your question.